# Can't dismiss ProgressDialog in onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

So, my progress dialog not dismiss in onPostExecute. I'm using fragment. I didn't know where my problem is. I had search and try many solution, but all of that not working

As I said before, I had try many solution but it didn't work. And my progress dialog still show.

This is how I run the AsyncTask

```
new FetchDataServer().execute();
```

And here is my AsyncTask class code. Tell me where my mistake is.

```
private class FetchDataServer extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = true;
            progressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Permintaan diproses", "Loading...");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            getOneWayResult(input_data);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            Log.d("HAHA","Executed");
            System.out.println("Masuk post execute");
            if(progressDialog.isShowing() || pd){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                pd = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I expected it to be dismiss immediately. It really disturbing my job. Currently in hurry to collect it. Thanks for your time.